# How should we determine the number of actors for best performance?

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am confused about actor-based programming design. Here is my scenario. I have files, and I want to process all lines in these files, then write information to a database. I created a main actor that is acting as a supervisor, and It has a database actor and “n” number of file actors(n is a number of files). Then each file actor creates k child actor for processing each line. Here is a diagram of the scenario that I mentioned.

[image: desgin]

Is It a good design? **What would be if I created only a supervisor, file actor and child actor?**

Note: I read [How to determine the number of actors to spawn in akka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10879296/how-to-determine-the-number-of-actors-to-spawn-in-akka) . I'm still confused.

Comment: You should benchmark stuff. I don't know what line workers do. You might get worse performance than by just looping through lines in your file actor.

Comment: It mostly depends on what kind of work line workers do. For example, if they do some CPU bound work, assigning fixed thread pool with n threads to file actors and looping over lines in file actor instead of sending them to line workers will improve performance. On the other hand if it is IO bound, for example making request for each line, it may increase performance to parallelize work with line workers. But as @DragisaKrsmanovic mentioned, you must benchmark.

Comment: Yes, They do CPU bound works. I know that actors are lightweight, and I can create millions of them. I am trying to understand actor-model design. I did some benchmarks for this case(only for the time); It is worth to utilize actor-model instead of the standard imperative way. What is the best way to measure benchmarks for this kind of problems(not only for the time, for example; scale up, scale out).